# How to solve this error in my gradle file

Tags: android

> Error:(16, 0) Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version
>   is 2.14.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the
>   distributionUrl in
>   /var/www/html/Pedometer-mass/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
>   to gradle-3.3-all.zip

Comment: show your Gradle code

Comment: #Fri Mar 03 22:10:26 CET 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

Answer (score 1):

Your gradle-wrapper.properties should look like this:

```
#Tue Apr 04 19:46:49 PDT 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Comment: thanks for response but  this is  i tried already..not solved with this

Comment: @Laxmanparlapelly did you mentioned that in question about what you have already tried? I think NO, so there you got such answer!

Comment: Also show your gradle settings, are you using 1) Use default gradle wrapper (recommended) or 2) Use local gradle distribution

Comment: yes im using default gradle wrapper (recommended) with uncheck offlinework